# A pointer to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

How would one define a variable named `scary` that is a pointer to a function that takes a single arg of type pointer to double and returns a pointer to a short?

Is this correct?
`short* (*scary)(double*)`

Comment: If only there was a way to test this...

Comment: [yes](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=short*+%28*scary%29%28double*%29)

Comment: All I scan say is you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have really googled for "*function pointer C*" in the first place, but I'll take your question as a confirmation of what you have *already* studied.

Yes, it's correct, take the following as an example:

```
short global = 2;
short * ptr_to_global = &global;

short* scary_fun(double* ptr) {
    return ptr_to_global;
}

int main(void) {
    double val = 22.0;
    double *ptr_to_val = &val;
    short* (*scary)(double*);
    scary = &scary_fun;
    printf("%d", *(scary(ptr_to_val))); // Prints "2"
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/TCvNzr)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
         scary                         -- scary
        *scary                         -- is a pointer to
       (*scary)(             )         -- a function on
       (*scary)(         arg )         --   parameter arg
       (*scary)(        *arg )         --     is a pointer to
       (*scary)( double *arg )         --     type double
      *(*scary)( double *arg )         -- returning a pointer to
short *(*scary)( double *arg )         -- type short
```

The subscript `[]` and function-call `()` operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so:

```
T *a[N]    -- a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N]  -- a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *f()     -- f is a function retunring pointer to T
T (*f)()   -- f is a pointer to a function returning T
```