# How do I define a pointer to a function in C and assign that pointer to a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am trying to define a pointer to a function in C then assign that pointer to a function.  All of the examples I have found are for functions with parameters and returns, but my function has neither.

Everything I have tried with the `MPLAB XC8` compiler cause either `'main.c:39:9: error: initializing 'void (*)()' with an expression of incompatible type 'void''` or `'main.c:39:18: error: expression is not assignable'` errors.

`scan_KP()` is a keypad scan function

This is my declaration for the pointer:

```
void (*KP_ScanPTR)(void);
```

Now I want the address of the function scan_KP assigned to the pointer; this is what I have tried:

```
(*KP_ScanPTR)() = scan_KP();
```

```
void (*KP_ScanPTR)() = scan_KP();
```

```
void (*KP_ScanPTR)(void) = scan_KP();
```

This one causes 'main.c:39:28: error: expected expression' but I didn't expect it to work anyway:

```
(*KP_ScanPTR)() = scan_KP(void);
```

I also tried this.  Interestingly I get: main.c:39:8: error: initializing 'int (*)()' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'.  So I think the declaration is correct since it knows there are no parameters and no return from scan_KP();:

```
int (*KP_ScanPTR)() = scan_KP();
```

This is the code example I was using as reference:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int subtraction (int a, int b) {
   return a-b;
}
int main() {
   int (*fp) (int, int)=subtraction;
   //Calling function using function pointer
   int result = fp(5, 4);
   printf(" Using function pointer we get the result: %d",result);
   return 0;
}
```

I have also reviewed this question [A pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737221/a-pointer-to-a-function) and this [Returning a pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538832/returning-a-pointer-to-a-function-in-c-syntax) The second shows a similar syntax

```
int funcA(int a, int b) { ... }
int (*funcB)(int, int) = funcA;
```

so I removed the parameters and return, but it does not.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you write `scan_KP()` you are calling that function, not getting its address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses in `scan_KP()` cause your function to be *called*, rather than its address taken. The result is an expression whose type is `void` — I'm not sure that counts as an expression at all, and it's definitely not the right type for assigning to a function pointer.

Just omit the parentheses, consistently with the two examples you quoted:

```
void (*KP_ScanPTR)(void) = scan_KP;
```

You can also add the address-of operator `&`:

```
void (*KP_ScanPTR)(void) = &scan_KP;
```

For the compiler this makes no difference, but for the human reader it makes it clearer that the function's address is being taken.